# Is there any way to stop getting spam mails from wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I'm continuously getting spam mails from my wordpress site. I've activated a plugin also, but still i receive. Any suggestions to overcome this issue?
[I'm getting mails like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CHzi.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What kind of emails are you speaking about? Are they from the Contact form or security email? Please provide some detailed information about the issue and the name of WordPress plugin which you used

Comment: I'm receiving mail from contact form. I've used a free plugin "HoneyBot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the emails are from Contact Forms. You just need to tighten up the security for the form. 
Use Google Recaptcha with Advanced Security which will stop the bots from submitting the contact forms.

Setup Google Recaptcha with Security Preference option set to "MOST SECURE". This will do.

Google Recaptcha Version 2 also has the setting for Security Preference.
Refer the below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but already added google recaptcha in the contact form.

Comment: Setup Google Recaptcha with Security Preference option set to "MOST SECURE".

Comment: Where could we find that settings? While integrating it asked for site key and secret key. After that added a shortcode like [recaptcha] in the contact form.

Comment: Refer this document: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/settings

Comment: Thanks for the document. Actually the option is not showing for google recaptcha v2 checkbox.

Comment: Even V2 has that feature. I have updated my answer. Refer that screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

**Install [Akismet](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/)**

Akismet checks your comments and contact form submissions against a global database of spam to prevent your site from publishing malicious content. The plug-in automatically checks all comments and filters out the ones that look like spam.

To activate you will need to register with Akismet and obtain an API Key. These keys are free for blogs and personal websites.

**Install the [Contact Form 7 Honeypot](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-honeypot/) Plugin**

This addition to Contact Form 7 adds basic honeypot anti-spam functionality to thwart spambots.

While some spam is manually submitted, the vast majority is posted by bots scripted in a specific way to submit spam to the largest number of form types. Using this method they somewhat blindly fill in fields, regardless of whether the field should be filled in or not. This is how a honeypot catches the bot — it introduces an additional field in the form that if filled out will cause the form not to validate.

**Add reCAPTCHA**

I must have spent a good couple of hours searching for an easy to use Captcha plug in. After many failed attempts I stumbled on Contact Form 7’s own built in form. To access, simply navigate to ‘Contact’ on the left hand menu bar and select ‘Integration’. You will be presented with a link to `google.com/recaptcha` – You will need to sign up to gain an API key. Next, add a shortcode to your contact form and reCAPTCHA is displayed.

—————————————————————————–

*These 3 easy steps provide a great barrier against spam and malicious emails being sent via your website’s contact form.*

Answer (score 0):

**Pass 1.**

plugin named **Akismet Anti-Spam**

**Pass 2.**

In this plugin configuration set:

Akismet's anti-spam rigor
Quietly, discard spam and more different spam without me seeing

Answer (score 0):

The best option I've found is **WordPress Zero Spam**: https://wordpress.org/plugins/zero-spam/

Doesn't require users to complete an annoying recaptcha and is highly effective. Bonus that it has a firewall using popular third-party IP blacklists, integrates with several popular form plugins, and keeps malicious and spam IPs from ever accessing the site.